# Could not determine metatable error binding list to asp.net datagridview

Tags: asp.net, linq, list, data-binding, datagridview

I am working with the following block of code ...

```
List<ThemeObject> themeList = (from theme in database.Themes
                            join image in database.DBImages on theme.imageID equals image.imageID
                            into resultSet
                            from item in resultSet
                            select new ThemeObject { Name = theme.Name, ImageID = item.imageID}).ToList();
dgvGridView.DataSource = themeList;
dgvGridView.DataBind();
```

The list object populates fine. The datagrid is setup with 2 columns.

- A textbox column for the "Name" which is bound to "Name"
- An image column which is bound to the "ImageID" field

When I execute the code I receive the following error on the DataBind()

> Could not determine a MetaTable. A
>   MetaTable could not be determined for
>   the data source '' and one could not
>   be inferred from the request URL. Make
>   sure that the table is mapped to the
>   dats source, or that the data source
>   is configured with a valid context
>   type and table name, or that the
>   request is part of a registered
>   DynamicDataRoute.

I'm not using any dynamicdataroutes as far as I can tell. Has anyone experienced this error before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are developing a Dynamic Data Entities web application (that's what the error you provided hints about), try this in your `Page_Init`:

```
dgvGridView.EnableDynamicData(typeof(ThemeObject));
```